# Trying to make a custom item for a server but it wont work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This command is supposed to give me a custom item for a server. Why won't it work?

```
give @p minecraft:netherite_sword
{
  display: {
    Name: "[{\"text\":\"Kindness (¾)\",\"color\":\"red\",\"italic\":false},
    Lore: ["{\"text\":\"\",This sword was forged from the deep depths of The Blazing Tundra it was weilded by the greatest swordsman in the land but was sadly lost many years ago.\"color\":\"dark_purple\",\"italic\":false}",
    Unbreakable: 1,
    HideFlags: 7,
    Health:32767s,
    Age:-32768,
    Enchantments: [
      {id: sharpness, lvl: 10},
      {id: smite, lvl:10},
      {id: bane_of_arthropods, lvl: 10},
      {id: fire_aspect, lvl: 10},
      {id: knockback, lvl: 10},
      {id: looting, lvl: 10},
      {id: sweeping_edge, lvl:10}
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what that does and why it work?

Answer (score 1):

building off of ginkgo's answer, you do in fact have multiple syntax errors. i'll go through them one by one here.

1. at `Name`, unclosed quotes; the full value needs to be wrapped in quotes
2. at `Name`, unexpected square brackets ([]); `Name` does not use square brackets as those are only used in lists, and it can only support one value
3. at `Lore`, unclosed square brackets; `Lore` is a list, and needs to be wrapped in square brackets
4. at `Lore`, malformed JSON string; there's an extra quote right after `text`
5. at `Unbreakable`, bad formatting; `Unbreakable` needs to be a Byte value, which means it needs to have `b` at the end of it (e.g. `1b` instead of just `1`)
6. at `HideFlags`, bad formatting;

there are also some tags that are simply not used in an item tag that you're giving to someone;

1. `Health`; only used in entities (things like mobs, players, etc.)
2. `Age`; only used in entities

edit; it's good to try to put it in a single line the way ginkgo did, since that's how commands are typed in Minecraft, but i'll post the command here formatted the way you did;

```
give @p minecraft:netherite_sword
{
  display: {
    Name: "{\"text\":\"Kindness (¾)\",\"color\":\"red\",\"italic\":false}",
    Lore: ["{\"text\":\"This sword was forged from the deep depths of The Blazing Tundra it was weilded by the greatest swordsman in the land but was sadly lost many years ago.\"color\":\"dark_purple\",\"italic\":false}"],
    Unbreakable: 1b,
    HideFlags: 7b,
    Enchantments: [
      {id: sharpness, lvl: 10},
      {id: smite, lvl:10},
      {id: bane_of_arthropods, lvl: 10},
      {id: fire_aspect, lvl: 10},
      {id: knockback, lvl: 10},
      {id: looting, lvl: 10},
      {id: sweeping_edge, lvl:10}
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple syntax errors. I recreated a working version your command using https://mcstacker.net/:

```
give @p netherite_sword{display:{Name:'{"text":"Kindness (¾)","color":"red","italic":false}',Lore:['{"text":"This sword was forged from the deep depths of The Blazing Tundra it was weilded by the greatest swordsman in the land but was sadly lost many years ago.","color":"dark_purple","italic":false}']},HideFlags:7,Unbreakable:1b,Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:sharpness",lvl:10s},{id:"minecraft:smite",lvl:10s},{id:"minecraft:bane_of_arthropods",lvl:10s},{id:"minecraft:knockback",lvl:10s},{id:"minecraft:fire_aspect",lvl:10s},{id:"minecraft:looting",lvl:10s},{id:"minecraft:sweeping",lvl:10s}]} 1
```

You also had some extra data, `Health:32767s,Age:-32768`, that I removed.